# Why does this regex replacement not work for JavaScript, but instead only work for other engines?

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to build a JavaScript function that transforms text into another format, from this:

```
MATCH 1
1.  [4-17]  `public direct`
2.  [18-29] `routing.key`
MATCH 2
1.  [35-41] `direct`
2.  [42-52] `routingkey`
```

To this:

```
MATCH 1: [Group 1: public direct] [Group 2: routing.key]
MATCH 2: [Group 1: direct] [Group 2: routingkey]
```

I've been messing with this code in my Chrome browser console using regex replacements, however it will not replace anything. Here is one of the approaches I've tried, `a` is the test object, the problem is on the second replacement:

```
a = "MATCH 1 \n\
1.  [4-17]  `public direct` \n\
2.  [18-29] `routing.key` \n\
MATCH 2 \n\
1.  [35-41] `direct` \n\
2.  [42-52] `routingkey`"

var repl = a.replace(/^(MATCH\s\d+)\s*/gm, "$1: ")
            .replace(/(\d+)\.\s+\[[^]]+\]\s*`([^`]*)`\s*/g, "[Group $1: $2]")
            .replace(/(?=MATCH\s\d+: )/g, "\n")

console.log(repl)
```

Studying regex101 demos, the pattern `` /(\d+)\.\s+\[[^]]+\]\s*`([^`]*)`\s*/g `` will [replace properly in PHP (PCRE)](http://regex101.com/r/gB3uR8/1#pcre) [and Python](http://regex101.com/r/gB3uR8/1#python), but [not on JavaScript](http://regex101.com/r/gB3uR8/1#javascript).

Why?

Comment: You must escape ] in character class because In javascript [^] mean all characters

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For [PCRE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_Compatible_Regular_Expressions) implementations, a closing square bracket on its own does not need to be escaped since it is the first meta character inside of the character class. In JavaScript, `[^]` represents a valid character class.

As quoted from the [PCRE documentation](http://www.pcre.org/pcre.txt):

> A closing square bracket on its own is not special by default. However, if the **PCRE_JAVASCRIPT_COMPAT** option is set,
>          a lone closing square bracket causes a compile-time error. If a closing
>          square bracket is required as a member of the class, it should be  the
>          first data character in the class (after an initial circumflex, if
>          present) or escaped with a backslash.

Therefore, you need to escape this character.

```
/(\d+)\.\s+\[[^\]]+\]\s*`([^`]*)`\s*/g
               ^^
```

[Working Demo](https://eval.in/196171)

Comment: @vks: Because `[^]` is a valid character class in JavaScript, but not in Python or PCRE.

Comment: I've [requested a fix for explanation of `[^]` in regex101](https://github.com/firasdib/Regex101/issues/134#issuecomment-56278324), which is now [`[status-completed]`](http://i.stack.imgur.com/xzPTQ.png). Thanks!